# Excel Add Sheet or Overwrite if Exists

Tags: vba, excel

In excel I have a macro that converts all of columns of an active sheet into an new sheet called "MasterList"

My problem is when I rerun that macro I get an error saying "That name is already taken." Try a different one.

I need my macro to overwrite MaterList sheet if it already exists.

Here is my code:

```
Sub ToArrayAndBack()
Dim arr As Variant, lLoop1 As Long, lLoop2 As Long
Dim arr2 As Variant, lIndex As Long

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With


ReDim arr2(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Count - ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count)

arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value


For lLoop1 = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For lLoop2 = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        If Len(Trim(arr(lLoop1, lLoop2))) > 0 Then
            arr2(lIndex) = arr(lLoop1, lLoop2)
            lIndex = lIndex + 1
        End If
    Next
Next

Sheets.Add.Name = "MasterList"

Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Value = arr2

Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Copy
Range("A2").Resize(lIndex + 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Rows(1).Delete

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: can't you just delete it if it exists and recreate it?

Comment: I don't think I can since I will be linking it to MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the sheet creation between on error resume and on error goto 0. The other solution is to loop through the workbook sheets collection and check if a sheet with that name exists.

Solution 1:

```
On Error Resume Next
Sheets.Add.Name = "MasterList"
On Error GoTo 0
```

Solution 2:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim found As Boolean
found = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name = "MasterList" Then
        found = True
        Exit For
    EndIf
Next
If Not found Then
    Sheets.Add.Name = "MasterList"
EndIf
```

To avoid relying on the fact that MasterList is active:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterList")
With ws
     .Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Value = arr2

     .Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Copy
     .Range("A2").Resize(lIndex + 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
     .Rows(1).Delete
End With
```

Comment: Tarik, thanks for the advice. I am a novice at VBA. Could you show me how either solution would look like in my code?

Comment: Solution 1: At first it creates a sheet named MasterList then it creates a new sheet. I need the data from the columns to go always into MasterList.

Comment: Solution 2: Converts all of the columns into the first column of the active sheet (i.e. Sheet OrderNumbers not MasterList) This is good but not quite what I need my code to do.

Comment: You can also check the error code in Solution 1 and delete the MasterSheet. In solution 2 you can Delete the MasterSheet if found is true.

Comment: Tarik, Thank you! Solution 2 worked! Is there a way to combine the columns from sheet named "OrderNumbers" instead of active sheet?

Comment: Yes, you can create a Worksheet variable, say wsOrder and set it to ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OrderNumbers"). You can then use wsOrder instead of ActiveSheet.

Comment: Do I delete this?                                                                                 ReDim arr2(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Count - ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count)                                                                                                     
arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
The add       wsOrder   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OrderNumbers")

Comment: No, I just meant that instead of using ActiveSheet which might lead to problems or force you to activate and deactivate sheets, you might as well refer to the sheet directly by getting a reference to it.

Comment: Can you please what the code would look like for creating a Worksheet variable to set it to ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OrderNumbers").

Also, I am not sure which lines to delete to remove active sheets.

Comment: Assuming OrderNumbers is the ActiveSheet, do this instead of `ActiveSheet.Range(...)`: `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OrderNumbers")` then use `ws.Range (...)`.